# How to make text in a label go onto the next line after it is a certain length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm working a little GUI in PyQt5/Python 3 for a project at school, but I'm having trouble with the text being cut off. Using label.adjustSize() doesn't fix it, and I can't think of any other way to get around it. I want to have it so that the label goes onto a new line, by creating either a new label, or using the same label, which would be preferable. The amount of characters that I will have the cutoff at is 62, so I only want the new line to be created if the label's text is longer than 62 characters.

Screenshot of problem here

[image]

Screenshot of Label Code here

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a layout so that the QLabel automatically adjusts the width of the QLabel in addition to setting the wordWrap property of QLabel to True:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label_content = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            wordWrap=True,
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop
        )
        self.button_view = QtWidgets.QPushButton("View Database")
        self.input_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Input:") 
        self.lineedit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.ask_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Ask Question")

        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.label_content)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.button_view, 0, 1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.input_label, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.lineedit, 2, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.ask_button, 2, 1)
        grid_layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)

        self.label_content.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sollicitudin aliquet mauris quis fringilla. Vivamus scelerisque mauris turpis, a imperdiet purus varius eget. Suspendisse pretium est id augue accumsan, vel luctus purus luctus. In hendrerit, turpis ac ultricies volutpat, urna enim hendrerit nisl, a sagittis arcu justo sit amet elit. Aenean bibendum, lacus nec commodo consequat, tortor lectus pulvinar velit, eu ultrices sem felis eget velit. Curabitur id ipsum sit amet tellus euismod mollis. Vivamus et imperdiet ligula. Donec malesuada fermentum felis, at egestas justo ultrices ac. In quis risus ut odio mattis commodo vel sit amet mauris. Vestibulum rutrum ligula tellus, quis faucibus urna imperdiet at. Praesent fermentum condimentum leo. Phasellus quis lacus sapien. Duis viverra sodales aliquet. Sed volutpat non nibh tincidunt blandit. Sed elementum sem at ligula pharetra hendrerit. Donec vel scelerisque mauris. ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks. I made [this](https://imgur.com/a/U8aj5kI) function to add a new line at the end of every new input, meaning it now does [this](https://i.imgur.com/LsU5JFR.png) for each line.